# Android Firebase Database query select with condition

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, query-string

I want to `SELECT * FROM products WHERE 'birthday' = true;`
But can I do the same with Firebase Database ?

I have tried

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref. child("products").orderByChild("birthday").equalTo(true).addChildEventListener ........
```

[Firebase Database image](http://m.imgur.com/gallery/IiF6dU9)

But it doesn't work.Please help. 
f my data structure is bad, please also advise how to create a better structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screenshot of the database shows that `birthday` is not a direct child of the product node: there's an extra step, `for_purpose`.

Your query must follow the schema precisely, therefore update your query code like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("products")
    .orderByChild("for_purpose/birthday")
    .equalTo(true)
    .addChildEventListener ...
```

---

Note that for this to work effectively, you must set up indexes for every possible `for_purpose` child in your security rules. Or at least for those that you use in queries. The indexes must match your query **exactly**, putting an index on `for_purpose` is not enough.

For this question, you need at least the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "products": {
      ".indexOn": [
        "for_purpose/birthday",
        "for_purpose/anniversary",
        "for_gender/male",
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi vzsg, could you advise how to set the security rule? Is this correct? 
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "products": {
      ".indexOn": ["for_purpose", "for_gender"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Hi vzsg, could you advise how to set the security rule? Is this correct? 
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "products": {
      ".indexOn": ["for_purpose", "for_gender"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: vzsg, your answer is correct, however,  the rule .IndexOn is not necessary in this case,  with reference to the documentation, indexes is for improving the query performance, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data   I have also tried ref.child("products").child ("for_purpose").equalTo(true).addChildEventListener........ But it doesn't work,  do you know what is the difference compared to your answer?

Comment: In your database, `for_purpose` is not a boolean (not even a primitive value), so `equalTo(true)` does not make sense. And indexes are important, otherwise performance will greatly suffer. Even though it's not _strictly required_ when using the client SDKs.

Comment: vzsg, Sorry for the typo. What I mean is ref.child("products").child ("for_purpose").orderByChild("birthday").equalTo(true).addChildEventListener........ does not work, could you tell the difference?

Comment: It's not working because `/products/for_purpose` does not exist (this is what your line of code tries to query from). Mine is the only valid query for your schema.